# What is the meaning behind this identity of modular forms and lattices?

Tags: modular-forms, integer-lattices

- The closest sphere packings in 8 dimensions is the $E_8$ lattice $\Lambda_8$.
- The closest sphere packings in 24 dimensions is the Leech lattice $\Lambda_{24}$.
- Create the function, $f(\tau)$ defined by:

$$f(\tau) =  \frac{\sum\limits_{x\in \Lambda_{24}} (-1)^{|x|^2\tau} }
{ \left(\sum\limits_{x\in \Lambda_{8}} (-1)^{|x|^2\tau}\right)^3  }$$

- We find $f(\tau)$ is a *modular function of weight 0*, i.e. it satisfies:

$$f(\tau) = f\left(\frac{ A\tau+B}{C\tau+D}\right)$$

for integers $A,B,C,D$ where $AD-BC=1$.

(*In particular we find $f(\tau)= 1-\frac{720}{j(\tau)}$ where $j$ is the j-invariant.)

Now is there any great meaning to this? Or is it entirely obvious that we would get a modular function of weight 0 from this fraction? And why not for other fractions involving other lattices in which the dimensions are multiples of each other?

Is there any great meaning behind the definition using the $E_8$ and Leech lattices, or does it more or less rely on the fact that $3\times 8=24$? I know that the Leech lattice in some sense can be though of as being made of 3 copies of $E_8$.

To me this is an amazing identity even more amazing than Euler's $e^{i\pi}+1=0$

Comment: It's  because the theta series of these lattices are modular forms; see Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*.

Comment: So is it important which lattices we use? Or will any work? e.g. a random lattice in 24D and another random one in 8D?

Comment: You want a unimodular lattice (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_lattice). Then the theta function is a modular form by Poisson summation. It is a lovely little piece of mathematics. A classical application of this circle of ideas is Jacobi's four-square theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem

Comment: I see. So you could use other 24D unimodular lattices and get other linear rational functions of j. I wonder what would you would get if you used a 32D unimodular lattice, say divided by E8^4. Probably not much.